# Varnish + Wordpress + Nginx - Prevent no-store no-cache must-revalidate headers

Tags: wordpress, nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl, timber

We launched a web app about a week ago, experienced a heavy load spike and were down for almost 2 hours. I won't mention the company by name, but we were leaning on them for recommendations to prevent this exact thing.

They said that since we were using Varnish, we could handle the traffic influx quite easily. However, we didn't verify caching was working as intended. It was not.

---

**TLDR:** Our web app is sending `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0` headers with requests and there's no indication of why that is.

**Where can I look to prevent these headers from being sent?**

PHP: 5.6
Nginx: 1.4.6
Varnish: 1.1
Wordpress: 4.6.12
Timber: 1.2.4

The linux admins we're working with have said they scoured the configs and haven't found anything specifying those headers except for AJAX requests.

```
#dont cache ajax requests

if(req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest" || req.url ~ "nocache" || req.url ~ "(control.php|wp-comments-post.php|wp-login.php|bb-login.php|bb-reset-password.php|register.php)")
```

Here's a curl from Pre-launch when we correctly configured Varnish to cache after forcing HTTPS(force-https plugin) on the site:

```
$ curl -Ik -H'X-Forwarded-Proto: *************
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Server: *****
Date: Sat, 03 Nov 2018 22:36:43 GMT
X-Varnish: 53061104
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
```

And from post launch:

```
curl -ILk ***********
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
X-Varnish: 691817320
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Server: ****
Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2018 19:17:02 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: X-Mapping-fjhppofk=33C486CB71216B67C5C5AB8F5E63769E; path=/
Age: 0
```

Force-https plugin: We activated this, updated the Varnish config to avoid a redirect loop and confirmed it was working a week prior to launch.

Plugins: These did not change, except for force-https.

Web App: It's an updated version of the previous app, complete redesign but nothing in the app from what I can tell is specifying `no-store no-cache` headers to be sent.

Where should I start? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is sending these headers is PHP engine.

It does so whenever you initiate a session, which clearly happens based on `Set-Cookie` presence.

Make sure that PHP sessions are initiated only when absolutely needed. By default, Varnish will not cache when response includes either `Set-Cookie` or "negative" `Cache-Control`, you have both.

So getting rid of extraneous `session_start()` and/or `setcookie()` calls is the key here.

You can find more info on when you can expect anti-caching headers sent [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/php/php-http-caching).

Comment: Daniel, thanks so much for clarification on this. It has been driving me mad. Here's the only occurrence of `session_start()` or `session_set_cookie_params()`

setup.php: https://gist.github.com/Mk-Etlinger/845dbe94462f4701964e75d123098597
I don't consider this extraneous, but perhaps it's the culprit.

Comment: That on it's own is able to kill Varnish caching entirely, if this is used within `functions.php` or similar location which will execute on every page. You may want to `grep -R X-Mapping .` in your entire project directory, to find what is setting the specific cookie from your example curl output.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Nothing returns from grepping `X-Mapping`. When I comment out the above code in the gist, the headers are removed. Unfortunately, we need to use sessions in our app to manage social logins sitewide. Why is this the default behavior when using sessions? Is there a specific reason why you aren't supposed to cache if you're using cookies or sessions?

Comment: Here is what I'm currently reading to get caught up =) https://blog.fortrabbit.com/mastering-http-caching

Comment: If caching was allowed in presence of cookies, this *may* possibly result in one user seeing  content designated for other users. Varnish does a sane default of bypassing cache/ing when cookies are set by backend or sent by a client. Things largely depend on the nature of a cookie. If this is for example a cookie for displaying your website in different languages, you can [tell Varnish to cache in presence of cookies](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish/varnish-cache-cookies). But if that's a login cookie (PHP session), then you should let Varnish do the default.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the backend, but at the very least, you can strip the annoying header, and/or bypass it in varnish with this vcl snippet;

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    # kill the CC header so that application downstream don't see it
    unset req.http.Cache-Control;

    # alternatively, you can also override that header with
    # set req.http.Cache-Control = "whatever string you desire";

    # you can also force the TTL
    beresp.ttl;

    # also, if you return now, the builtin.vcl (https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl)
    # doesn't get executed; this is generally the one deciding content is uncacheable
    return (deliver);
}
```